# Jpa concurrent access to counter variable

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, concurrency, jpa-2.0, java-ee-7

My use case is as simple as it can get : I want to give multiple users the possibility to increment a counter by 1. Now with optimistic concurrency strategy it can happen that two user try to update the counter at the same time and an OptimisticLockException is thrown. If I understood correctly the OptimisticLockException is wrapped into a System Exception if I dont explicitly call EntityManager#flush. Now when this happens the transaction is rolled back. But how can I accomplish that the transaction is retried until it finally succeeds ? Since I only want to increment the counter by 1 I don't have to deal with merging the two updates or so. I only want to be absolutely sure that no increment gets lost and I also don't want to go back to the user and ask him to perform his increment again.

Comment: Well, catch the exception and restart a transaction until it succeeds. I'm not 100% sure, but using a query like `update ... set counter = counter + 1` should prevent any risk of loss, especially if you set the isolation level to serializable.

Comment: You could also use a sequence if your database supports it.

Comment: so you are saying that using a jpql update query should be safe enough for this use case ? Is it also more safe than obtaining the entitiy, incrementing the value and then persisting the updated entity again ?

Comment: It's obviously faster and more atomic, since the incrementation is done by the database itself. The chances for a concurrent update are thus lower. And I can't offer you string guarantees, but my common sense tells me that it's atomic, at least if the isolation level is serializable. Check the documentation of your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your use case is just an example for concurrent access or some kind of test or showcase, right?

If not, you can just let the database do it and either use a sequence as suggested or encapsulate it in your own database script which can be used by an arbitrary client.

If so, then it does not matter if it's just a counter or any other operation done by a query or a persisted entity - the problem is always the same: At least 2 different requests try to trigger the same update and one will fail.

So what you can do is either handle the problem *specifically* for your use case and decide for example to reload the changed entity and go from there or implement a *generic* retry mechanism, which retries the same statement / use case for a certain time / number of tries (you shouldn't do it without that, since it can seriously hurt your application). If you want to use an existing implementation, try to google for `RetryProxy`.